# Erro ao criar XML com XmlWriter

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Eu preciso criar um XML, porem quando eu tento criar 2 elementos esse da erro, como eu faço pra gerar 1 XML com dois elementos?
segue meu codigo

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("books.xml"))
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("book");
            writer.WriteElementString("title", "Graphics Programming using GDI+");
            writer.WriteElementString("author", "Mahesh Chand");
            writer.WriteElementString("publisher", "Addison-Wesley");
            writer.WriteElementString("price", "64.95");
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("newBook");
            writer.WriteElementString("title", "Graphics Programming using GDI+");
            writer.WriteElementString("author", "Mahesh Chand");
            writer.WriteElementString("publisher", "Addison-Wesley");
            writer.WriteElementString("price", "64.95");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Codigo do erro:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Token StartElement in state EndRootElement would result in an invalid XML document. Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is set to ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want to write an XML fragment. '

Comment: Olha esse link que tem alguns exemplos de como fazer http://www.macoratti.net/12/09/xml_cur2.htm

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa definir o elemento ROOT - ele é o elemento raiz da sua árvore.
O primeiro elemento que você deverá criar, será justamente esse nó.

```
writer.WriteStartElement("root");
```

Seu código completo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("books.xml"))
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("root");

            writer.WriteStartElement("book");
            writer.WriteElementString("title", "Graphics Programming using GDI+");
            writer.WriteElementString("author", "Mahesh Chand");
            writer.WriteElementString("publisher", "Addison-Wesley");
            writer.WriteElementString("price", "64.95");
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("newBook");
            writer.WriteElementString("title", "Graphics Programming using GDI+");
            writer.WriteElementString("author", "Mahesh Chand");
            writer.WriteElementString("publisher", "Addison-Wesley");
            writer.WriteElementString("price", "64.95");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarceloHenriqueDosReis Talvez por se tratar de uma coleção de `<book>` fosse interessante chamar o root de `<books>` e não possuir dois tipos de objetos dentro dele. Ao invés de `<book>` e `<newBook>`, você deveria ter apenas `<book>` e ou adicionar um elemento `<newBook>true</newBook>` ou ainda apenas o atributo `<book newBook="true">`.

Comment: Isso mesmo Leandro, o nó books seria mais apropriado. Quanto a repetição dos objetos, acredito que o autor da pergunta apenas postou como exemplo com o ctrlC + ctrlV.